# Connecting To Separate 'Database Connect File'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two php files. One PHP file is my details to connect to a mysql database

The second PHP file performs a SELECT function on the database

My problem is that the second PHP file does not seem to be actioning the first PHP file.

I have just moved to using PDO commands instead of MYSQL commands. When I used a Require('connect_db'); function everything worked. Since I've moved to PDO commands it does not work

I am getting the error

```
 Call to a member function execute () on a non object in................
```

My code is as below:-

The connect_db file is (I have not shown the strings for password, user , database:-

```
        try
             {
             $mysql_link= new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8",$username,$password);
             $mysql_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
             $mysql_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
             echo "Connected Success";
             }
             catch(PDOException $e)
             {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             }
```

My SELECT file is as follows:-

```
             Require('connect_db.php');          

             $stmt=$mysql_link->prepare("SELECT cif_train_uid,cif_stp_indicator FROM schedule WHERE cif_train_uid=:cif_train_uid");
             $stmt->execute(array(':cif_train_uid'=>$cif_train_uid));
             foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
              echo $row['cif_train_uid'];   
              echo $row['cif_stp_indicator'];
             }
             $mysql_link=null;
```

If I merge all the code into one file it works fine. (Both scripts are in the same folder). So its just the Require () function that does not seem to be working but I cannot see why. Any help gratefully received

Comment: Try to dump `$mysql_link` right after `require()`, to see if it's a `PDO` object.

Comment: Thanks Grimv01k you've made me see that it was not a PDO object and the reason for that was that I had uploaded the wrong connect_db file ..............ie I had uploaded the old mysql one and not the new PDO one

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see that a included / required file results in a problem that does not occur when you put the code in the including file, is when there are no opening php tags in the included file:

```
<?php
^^^^^ this...
try
{
   $mysql_link= new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8",$username,$password);
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I have seen my mistake and commented above to Grimv01k

Comment: @user2635961 Ah, you should probably delete your question then.